# Create Basemap with custom Data

Tags: open-source-gis

I am getting trouble with creating a basemap with my own data. I have huge data. So I don't want to use any other basemap platform like leaflet or Mapbox or Google.

I have tried with ArcGIS server and successfully complete the process. But Now my challenge is to create it with an open source platform.

By which platform I can create Basemap with my data?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please focus on one question and create a new thread for the other questions. That way we can focus on one question at a time and answer it thoroughly.

Comment: Those all are relevant question. I have just put it in a numbered way.

Comment: They are all relevant but it is better to split them into separate questions. That way it would easier to select a correct answer. If you ask several questions in one question you risk having answers that are both correct and wrong at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange @DevilsDream! As R.K. explained, this site's format is to have only one question per thread. You can open as many threads as you like. This way it's easy to find relevant questions and answers in the future.

Comment: By create a basemap, do you mean design it and generate map tiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your basemaps with [Tilemill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) and serve it yourself using [Tilestream](https://github.com/mapbox/tilestream). Another option would be to use [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/).